# Unity Input System, context menu option missing

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, input, system, contextmenu

I'm currently trying to learn some Unity and started with new input system, but after installing it from Package Manager, nothing happened. From doc i know that there should be an additional option in context menu, but i got nothing. Am I forgotting something?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean that you are missing the "Input Actions" option. If so, you probably need to activate the new input system.

Menu "Edit" - "Project Settings". Select the "Player" view and under "Other Settings" you will find the "Active Input Handling" option. Make sure it is set to "Input System Package (New)". Unity will restart after a change.

[image]

Comment: done that and after restart nothing changed, i tried picking "Input System Package (New)" and "Both", but in both cases option isn't showing.

Comment: That is strange... Try right-clicking on the "Input System" folder in Project - Packages, and select "Reimport All". It should refresh the whole package... If that does not help, have you included any other assets that might interfere with the new Input System?